React-Native Expo: Image Cropping Library
I'm currently developing an application using React Native and Expo, and I need a reliable image cropping library in which the user can select the region he wants to crop. After extensive research and testing various libraries, I haven't found a compatible solution that works seamlessly with both React Native and Expo.
What libraries can you recommend?
What I've Tried:

react-native-image-crop-picker: Requires linking native modules, which is not supported in the Expo managed workflow
expo-image-cropper
react-native-image-editor

